# Why and when should I use innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have a variable called 'name' that i need to show in a certain place in the page. Do i need to use innerHTML or can i put a `<script>` right in the middle of the body html?

```
...
<span id="name-here"></span>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("name-here").innerHTML = name;
</script>
```

or

```
...
<span><script type="text/javascript">document.write(name);</script></span>
...
```

Comment: i know that is very common to put <?php print $name; ?> in the middle of the html (that´s how the wordpress loop works), but i have never saw this be done with javascript....

Comment: Can't you just do neither and do it proper by using the DOM instead?

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29).

Comment: only use `innerHTML` if you're actually altering HTML. As for `document.write()`, don't use it. Grab the element you want to use with `document.getElementById("name-here")` and use the `textContent` property to assign `name` to it

Comment: what should i use instead of document.write?

Comment: because nether innerHTML nor textContent would never replace this:   `document.write('<a href="' + name + '">';):`

Answer (score 0):

You should use only option of innerHTML property for insert content into HTML page.

```
<span id="name-here"></span>
<button onclick="displayName()">click</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function displayName(){
     var name="Bill";
     document.getElementById("name-here").innerHTML = name;
  }
</script>
```

Avoid use option of documet.write because that is bad practice.

Answer (score -2):

It depends if that by the time the browser reaches the line

```
<span><script type="text/javascript">document.write(name);</script></span>
```

if the variable would be ready and available for rendering, if it's there then I think it shouldn't be a problem to do it this way, otherwise you can defer it until the end of the page where the variable would be ready and available.

Comment: I didn't know that using `document.write` is [discouraged](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29)